# Does the Claws evolution give 2 attacks or only one attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, natural-weapon, summoner, eidolon, unchained

Well, it's very simple. The Evolution's name is "Claws" (plural), and the name of the Natural Attack in the [table](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Table_Natural_Attacks_by_Size) is "Claw" (singular). Does the Claws evolution give 2 attacks, each dealing 1d4 + STR / 2 damage, or does it only give one?

Comment: I assume you're talking about this evolution? http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons#TOC-Claws-Ex-
Is anything unclear there? The description seems pretty specific about it being 2 claw attacks.

Comment: @Erik I just have to learn to read, so it seems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Claws evolution grants 2 attacks

You can find the description for this evolution [here](http://aonprd.com/SummonerEvolutions.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> An eidolon has a pair of vicious claws at the end of its limbs, **giving it two claw attacks**. The claws deal 1d4 points of damage (1d6 if Large, 1d8 if Huge).

It is quite clear that the evolution grants two attacks from this description